# Retrieve/fetch records from DYNAMICS 365 crm using C# code

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamics-crm

- Problem 1:

  I am new to MICROSOFT DYNAMICS CRM 365. I have few tables with my CRM like(Account,Customer).I want to fetch all data from table account.

Below is my sample code for connection:(not sure this is correct or not but getting output message that i am connected to CRM)

```
public void ConnectToMSCRM(string UserName, string Password, string SoapOrgServiceUri)  
    {  
        try  
        {  
            ClientCredentials credentials = new ClientCredentials();  
            credentials.UserName.UserName = UserName;  
            credentials.UserName.Password = Password;  
            Uri serviceUri = new Uri(SoapOrgServiceUri);  
            OrganizationServiceProxy proxy = new OrganizationServiceProxy(serviceUri, null, credentials, null);  
            proxy.EnableProxyTypes();  
            _services = (IOrganizationService)proxy;  
            Response.Write("Connected to CRM \n");  
}
```

I need all data to be retrieved on button click event .
Output should be: result of `"select * from ABC"`;

- Problem 2:

if possible please suggest how to fetch records using given column name.
Output should be: result of `"select * from ABC where ColumnName="test"`;

Comment: Don't add unnecessary tags to attract views,I have removed those.

Comment: "Select * from ABC where ColumnName="test"; ?? you mean  "Select test from ABC " isn't that ?

Comment: You are right but that i have mentioned for explaining only. I need to retrieve data from table(from dynamic crm online) using C# code and list those data  .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fetching all entities list  into List

```
    var allEntities = **GetEntities(_service);**
    foreach (var Entity in allEntities)
    {
        ddlEntityName.Items.Add(Entity.LogicalName);
    }
```

//Function with single parameter (oganizationservice as a parameter)

//This will fetch Table/Entity Name Like ACCOUNT,CONTACT from Microsoft Dynamics CRM

```
public Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Metadata.EntityMetadata[] GetEntities(IOrganizationService organizationService)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> attributesData = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        RetrieveAllEntitiesRequest metaDataRequest = new RetrieveAllEntitiesRequest();
        RetrieveAllEntitiesResponse metaDataResponse = new RetrieveAllEntitiesResponse();
        metaDataRequest.EntityFilters = EntityFilters.Entity;

        XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas myReaderQuotas = new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas();
        myReaderQuotas.MaxNameTableCharCount = 2147483647;

        // Execute the request.

        metaDataResponse = (RetrieveAllEntitiesResponse)organizationService.Execute(metaDataRequest);

        var entities = metaDataResponse.EntityMetadata;

        return entities.OrderBy(x => x.LogicalName).ToArray();//to arrange in ascending order
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What about query expression?

This is your query :

```
Select * from ABC where ColumnName="test";
```

And this is the `QueryExpression`:

```
QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression()
{
    EntityName = Contact.EntityLogicalName,
    ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("address1_telephone1"),
};
```

to excute the query, this is how :

```
DataCollection<Entity> entityCollection = _services.RetrieveMultiple(query).Entities;

// Display the results.
foreach (Contact entity in entityCollection)
{
    Console.WriteLine("my test: {0}", entity.address1_telephone1);
}
```

Regards

Comment: Thanks @Coding4Fun for Reply ..please share more knowledge regarding this .. i am not understanding **EntityName = ABC.EntityLogicalName**

Comment: I Edited my answer,.. In fact ABC is your custom CRM Entity, like Account, User. Read this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.query.queryexpression.aspx , I'll give more information later

Comment: I have gone through your suggestion and i tried with the same code _QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression()
{
    EntityName = ABC.EntityLogicalName,
    ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("test"),
};_ but getting error in ABC.EntityLogicalName .... **It shows ABC does not exist in current context.**

Comment: Waht is realy the name of your entity in CRM. ABC is just  an exampe, its fake.

Comment: Ok use a real entity (contact) and a columnset (address1_telephone1). ABC is fake, it is just an example